Python: clicked.connect in PyQt6 project does not work
I have created main.py in which create instance of pyqt6 interface (with one simple button). I sent created interface to another class and try to organize behavior of this button and find that:
this works:
self.ui.btn_load.clicked.connect(lambda: self.load_data())

This doesn't work:
self.ui.btn_load.clicked.connect(self.load_data)

And I don't know what's that difference. In main.py class second case works fine.
More details:
Python: 3.11.2
Editor: VSCode
main.py
import sys
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

from MainScreenUI import Ui_MainWindow
from Behaviour import Behaviour

class AppController(QMainWindow):
    
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        super().__init__()
        
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        start_tab = Behaviour(self.ui)
        
        self.show()
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = AppController()
    sys.exit(app.exec())

Behaviour.py
from MainScreenUI import Ui_MainWindow
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

class Behaviour:
    
    def __init__(self, ui:Ui_MainWindow) -> None:
        self.ui = ui
        
        # self.ui.btn_load.clicked.connect(lambda: self.load_data())
        self.ui.btn_load.clicked.connect(self.load_data)
        print('init behaviour')

    def load_data(self):
        print('click in behaviour class')
        

P.S. In this case I only recreate the situation. In the real project I have a complicated interface for analysis data with many tabs, buttons and fields. So I won't separate behaviour to different classes.
Did you know why self.ui.btn_load.clicked.connect(self.load_data) doesn't work in Behaviour.py?

We're missing MainScreenUI for a reproducible example.

Why you dont want to use the lambda :  who basicaly create a throw away function who call your function

Use self.start_tab = Behaviour(self.ui) to prevent immediate garbage-collection. The only reason why the lambda seems to "work" is because it creates a closure over self that keeps the instance of Behaviour alive.
